# Compile libraries for Kotlin android,rust and go

Tags: android, kotlin, go, architecture, swig

This question is exploratory in nature, not sure if this fits stack overlflow Q&A.

Context:

I have a library written in golang that I need to compile for multiple services to use.

These services are in Kotlin android,Rust,Golang.

The only option I am aware of is using something like SWIG to compile the go library for different languages.

Problem:

1. I don't think SWIG works for Kotlin.

I am trying to fish for the best methods to do this and different approaches this can be done.

Comment: So it looks like SWIG compiles Go into C or C++?  That doesn't really help you for Kotlin.  Kotlin on Android can consume C (or extern "C"-ed C++) via JNI, but you'd need to find a way to generate the JNI functions, and you'd need to write the Java/Kotlin side wrappers to match it (I'm not sure if Kotlin can directly connect with JNI, or if you'd need to write Java classes and just access them in Kotlin).  But either way you'll need to write an interface layer likely by hand.

Comment: SWIG can generate JNI for you so this is probably feasible if your go library has C exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any language that can generate a C shared library and header file you can use SWIG to wrap it. Equally for any language that runs within a JVM and can call Java classes you can make use of SWIG's auto generated Java bindings.

With that we can therefore do a sequence of things that looks like this:

Go -> C -> JNI -> Java -> Kotlin

It's actually fairly sane. I've put together an example below for this to show how it works since I was curious having never written Go nor Kotlin before. (Take this with a pinch of salt therefore, I've probably not hit "best practice" for either!)

This example assumes you have a working JDK/JRE, C compiler, Go installation and kotlinc.

My demo.go looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

//export TestGoFunc
func TestGoFunc(str *C.char) *C.char {
        fmt.Printf("Got string: %s\n", C.GoString(str))
        return nil
}

func main() {}
```

And hello.kt looks like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Hello, World!")
    test.TestGoFunc("Another string")
}
```

To wrap this I wrote the following SWIG interface:

```c
%module test

%{
#include "golib.h"
%}

%include <typemaps.i>

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
  }
%}

// Assuming you don't care about these in your library silence/neaten stuff
#define _Complex
%ignore _GoString_;
%ignore GoComplex64;
%ignore GoComplex128;
%ignore GoSlice;
%ignore GoInterface;

%include "golib.h"
```

This is a fairly standard SWIG interface for targeting Java - it hides some of the stuff in the generated header file we don't care about and autoloads the .so file inside Java using a pragma for us.

Then I put together a small Makefile to build everything since there's a bunch of steps to this build:

```
all: libtest.so hello.jar

golib.so: demo.go
        go build -o golib.so -buildmode=c-shared demo.go

test_wrap.c: golib.so test.i
        swig3.0 -java -Wall test.i

libtest.so: test_wrap.c
        gcc -shared -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.c -o libtest.so ./golib.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux

hello.jar: hello.kt
        javac *.java
        kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar -cp .
        jar uvf hello.jar *.class
```

If we build and run this then it all works nicely:

```
$ make
go build -o golib.so -buildmode=c-shared demo.go
swig3.0 -java -Wall test.i
gcc -shared -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.c -o libtest.so ./golib.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
javac *.java
kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar -cp .
jar uvf hello.jar *.class
adding: test.class(in = 302) (out= 216)(deflated 28%)
adding: testJNI.class(in = 389) (out= 268)(deflated 31%)
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java -jar hello.jar
Hello, World!
Got string: Another string
```

I'd be tempted to use `-buildmode=c-archive` for Go to build a static library and then link that into the SWIG shared object instead just to keep things simpler in that regards though.